# react-native-webview Navigate to a list of URLs?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-webview

As the question title says, I am trying to navigate to a list of urls using React Natives WebView component.  Here is how I am attempting to accomplish this:

```
export default function App() {
  
  const webViewScript = `
    let urls = ["http://example1.com", "http://example2.com", "http://example3.com"];
    urls.forEach((url) => {
      window.location = url;
      window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(document.documentElement.innerHTML);
    });

    true; // note: this is required, or you'll sometimes get silent failures
  `;

  return (
    <WebView
      source={{ uri: navUri }}
      onMessage={(event) => {
        // do something with `event.nativeEvent.data`
        alert(event.nativeEvent.data);
      }}
      injectedJavaScript={webViewScript}
    />
  );
}
```

However, the foreach loop in the injected javascript does not block, so example3.com is the only url that actually loads.  I've considered keeping a counter variable in localStorage and using that to index the array, incrementing after each page load before redirecting to the next URL (since a local variable would lose its state upon page change).  But I feel there might be a better way to accomplish what I am trying to achieve, and so I am reaching out to others on SO for your valuable input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to navigate to a list of urls then i think your approach might be complicating it a bit.

The webview has callback prop ´onLoadEnd´ for when a site has loaded that you can use to trigger the next navigation.

Also you do not need to store a variable in localStorage, reacts useState is perfect for this.

[Demo](https://snack.expo.dev/J3ftvhLgS)

```
const urls = [
  'https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview',
  'https://stackoverflow.com/',
  'https://expo.dev/',
];

export default function App() {
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);

  return (
    <WebView
      style={styles.container}
      source={{ uri: urls[activeIndex] }}
      onLoadEnd={() => {
        if (activeIndex + 1 === urls.length) return;
        setActiveIndex(activeIndex + 1);
      }}
    />
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this response, went ahead an marked it as the answer.  I had an intuitive feeling that there was a better way to accomplish this, and I am pretty sure it is the method you provided.  Brand new to react-native, so this was very helpful for me.  I appreciate it.

Comment: I'm happy to help!